# VS2008 C#: most optimum way to remove multiple occurrences

Tags: c#

Lets say I have a collection of words such as follows:

{"hello", "world", "my", "hello", "world", "sam", "world"}

I would like to remove any multiples such that result would be like the following after parsing.

{"hello", "world", "my", "sam"}

How can I do that in **most optimized way.**

Comment: which framework? 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4?

Comment: How many millions string you think you will need to parse?

Comment: Homework?  If so just tag it as such

Comment: There's no such thing as "most optimized". When you optimize a thing for speed, you usually end up deoptimizing it for use of memory, and vice versa. When you optimize a thing for good performance for small cases, you usually end up deoptimizing it for performance on large cases. And vice versa. You have to say what you're optimizing *for*.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know about most optimum, but System.Linq.Enumerable.Distinct is certainly the most concise way.

```
// using System.Linq;
string[] words = {"hello", "world", "my", "hello", "world", "sam", "world"};
var uniqueWords = words.Distinct();
```

Comment: Just checked and Distinct does in fact use a Set as its implementation.

Comment: +1 as this uses the correct data structure behind the scenes.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using .NET 3.5, you can insert them into a `HashSet<T>`, then (if you want the order maintained) go through your original list and add the item that's in the hashset. This will be O(n), as it does it in a single pass

```
string[] values = new[] {"hello", "world", "my", "hello", "world", "sam", "world"};

HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
List<string> newValues = new List<string>();  // or LinkedList<string>, if you don't want the cost of backing array resizes

foreach (string val in values) {
    if (!hashSet.Contains(val)) {
        newValues.Add(val);
        hashSet.Add(val);
    }
}

// newValues is the result you want
```

If it's .NET 2.0, you get the same performance using a `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of `HashSet<T>`, with `null` as the values

Comment: This is optimal in terms of space. In terms of speed - create empty HashSet, empty LinkedList, go through the original list/array, check if element is in the set: if not, then add it to both the set and the list. You will end up with a LinkedList which preserves the original order. If you do not care about the order, then just use the HashSet. Then iterate over it once you actually need the values.

Comment: This is almost exactly how LINQ's `Distinct` method works, although `Distinct` yields the distinct values as it goes rather than adding them to a new list.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor for the [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) will filter the list for you.

```
var distinctItems = new HashSet<string>((IEnumerable<string>)myItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely more efficient ways then this, I'm just a Linq fan ;)

```
IEnumerable<string> reducedList =
    originalList.GroupBy(s => s).Select(s => s.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> myStrings = new List<string>(){"hello", "world", "my", "hello", "world", "sam", "world"};

var b = ((from a in my myStrings select a).Distinct()).ToList();
```